# Can these questions be answered with these answers?

Tags: grammar, questions, prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases, wh-questions

I am trying to reach the question form by going through its standard sentence form. In my native language, Turkish,

The question form of

> I'm talking about the money that is for your education = I'm talking
> about the money for your education

can be

> For whom are you talking about the money? -- OR -- Whom are you
> talking about the money for?

Of course, you can ask "what money are you talking about", however, I'm trying to transform the standard form to the question form one-to-one.

Another example,
The question form of

> I'm talking about the book on my desk

can be

> On what are you talking about the book? -- OR -- What are you talking
> about the book on?

Could you please tell me whether these answers can belong to these questions, or not.
In other words, could you tell me whether these questions can be answered with these answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggested wordings as questions are all ungrammatical. There is no "one-to-one" formulaic way to convert the answers to the appropriate questions.

You will have to say something like

> What is the money you are talking about for?

or, if the person is the unknown you are asking about

> Who is this education money you are talking about for?

For the second example

> Which book are you talking about?

Comment: In this case, the questions like "For what did you do that in exchange?" or "What did you do that in exchange for?" are not grammatical, they are totally ungrammatical.
Why I said this one is because someone in the forum said to me that "they are grammatical and equal to the question "In exchange for what did you do that?".

However, what I understand from your answer is that they are not equal to each other at all, and "In exchange for what did you do that" is grammatical while "For what did you do that in exchange" is not.

Do you agree?

Comment: I agree that the first is grammatical. and the second is not. But no one would ever say or write either.